# How to stop open browser on server with react-app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm facing an issue on remote development always opening the browser on Server side while I'm developing on client side.

The setup is :

- a project created with create-react-app on my server machine.
- a vscode-server remote ssh setup on the same server
- vscode with remote-ssh plugin on client side
- `BROWSER=none` setup in [.env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) project (which is working fine starting the project from the server directly).
- `--no-browser` seems to work like `BROWSER=none`

The thing is, developing in remote with vscode [override the `BROWSER` env](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/3d58b4623bcf3e85d80af78c45efaf3f4fd44892/src/vs/server/node/extensionHostConnection.ts#L63) conditionally to a `without-browser-env-var` arg seems to be my nemesis.

As far I can investigate I get the process executed in vscode console which seems pass args and it look like that :
`Running ssh connection command... /Users/hollypony/.vscode-server/bin/hashcode/bin/code-server --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level off`

The main question is: How to stop opening browser on my Server when I start my project through the client ?

Alternative question: There is a way to configure somewhere the `--without-browser-env-var` arg and how considering ssh environment ?

Note: I've found that display the content of env.BROWSER that refer to : `/Users/hollypony/.vscode-server/bin/helpers/browser.sh` on react-scripts

EDIT:

- react-scripts v5.0.1
- vscode v1.73
- Remote - SSH v0.96.0
- Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files v0.84.0
- Remote Explorer v0.2.0

> Update 03/03/23
>
> I found a hack editing the `"terminal.integrated.env.${targetServerType-osx for me}` on the Client vscode settings with value : `{ "BROWSER": "none" }`
>
> This way Im overriding over the override of BROWSER. And as mentioned it's a hack more than a pleasant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the start command in your `package.json` file to include the --no-browser option:

```
"start": "react-scripts start --no-browser"
```

This will prevent the the opening of the browser !

Comment: Seems working like the `BROWSER=none` I mean it work locally no problem but not with the vscode remote which is overrided anyway

Comment: Try to run the command directly from terminal in vscode remote before adding it to package.json and see if it works

Comment: I got the same result. Browser on server still opening a new tab

Comment: I've edit the post to add a hack. As you can see this is reallly not a react-script/create-react-app issue which is working fine but a true vscode env override of BROWSER var while on client/server relation.